# Is it possible to host Flutter web on any common web hostings or is there any compatibility check that I need to be aware of?

Tags: flutter, hosting, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

I created a site with Dart/Flutter and now I would like to host it. I saw from the documentation that coke hosting I could use Firebase Hosting, GitHub Pages, etc. but I was wondering if it was possible to use the most common web hostings like SiteGround/Aruba/GoDaddy, etc.. Do I need to check anything in particular to see if it is compatible with flutter? Or just put the generated code in the web folder on any hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Flutter app compiled for the web becomes just a bunch of static HTML and JavaScript files. Those can be hosted on pretty much any service, and is definitely not restricted to just Firebase.